# the application says not responding, even after i used AsyncTask to relieve the load on the main thread

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

this code parses a locally stored xml file and then creates a dynamic UI from the parsed data, though i haven't completed the UI part. It was working fine till yesterday and now suddenly it is not responding.

```
public class XML_PARSER extends Activity {

String TAG= "XML_PARSER";
List optionList = new ArrayList(); ;
Document dom;
Document doc;
Menu mymenu=null;

String msg=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parser);
    new ParseXML().execute();
   }

private class ParseXML extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Document>{
    @Override
protected Document doInBackground(Integer... params) {

     DocumentBuilderFactory dbf= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document dom1=null;
    try {
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.xml_parser/raw/options");
        InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.options);

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        dom1=db.parse(is);
        Log.i(TAG,"parsing done");

    }

    catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(SAXException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dom1;

}
    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Document d) {
        ParseDocument(d); 
        //onCreateOptionsMenu(mymenu);
        text();
        }



}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void ParseDocument(Document dom){
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();
    Node node;

    NodeList n1= docEle.getElementsByTagName("Option");
    if(n1!=null && n1.getLength()>0){

        for(int i=0;i<n1.getLength();i++){

            node=n1.item(i);

            Element e1=(Element)n1.item(i);
```

it is somehow getting stuck at this getOption() as the log is not getting printed if written below while it is getting printed if written above it.

```
            Option e = getOption(e1,node);
            Log.i(TAG,"Parse Document reached");

            optionList.add(e);



            }

        }

    }

private Option getOption(Element el,Node parent){

    String name= getTextValue(el,"Name");
    String type = el.getAttribute("type");


    Option op = new Option(name,type);
    fillSubOptions(op, el, parent);

    return op;


}

private String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName){
    String textVal=null;
    NodeList n1 = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if(n1!=null && n1.getLength()>0){
        Element el= (Element)n1.item(0);
        textVal =el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    }
    return textVal;
}


private void fillSubOptions(Option op, Element el, Node parent){
    Element ele;
    Node node;
    String name = null;
    NodeList n1 = el.getElementsByTagName("Option");
    int count =0;
    if(n1!=null && n1.getLength()>0){
        for(int i=0;i<n1.getLength();i++){
            ele = (Element)n1.item(i);
            node= n1.item(i);
            if((node.getParentNode()).equals(parent)){
                name= getTextValue(ele, "Name");
                count= op.printSubOptions(count);
                op.setSubOptions(name);
            }
        }
    }

}




@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.mymenu=menu;
    Iterator<Option> it= optionList.iterator();
    int count=0;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Option e= (Option)it.next();
        if(e.getType().equals("menu")){
            count++;
            menu.add(0,count,0,e.getName());
        }
    }


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.parser, menu);
    return true;
}




public class Option {


    String name;
    String type;
    String parent;
    int count;
    ArrayList<String> subOptions;
    Option(String name,String type)
    {
        setName(name);
        setType(type);

        subOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
        parent = null;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public void setSubOptions(String subOption) {
        (this.subOptions).add(subOption);

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int printSubOptions(int count) {
        Iterator<String> it = (this.subOptions).iterator();
        if(it.hasNext()){

            while(it.hasNext()){

                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;


    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;

}


}
```

Comment: If your purpose is to make the UI from the parsed xml, why even use AsyncTask there?

Comment: And for the question itself, you can find the spot very easily by adding comments all the way in getOption, fullSubOptions etc. or debugging with breakpoints.

Comment: Have you checked the ANR log file?

Comment: @niko-i am first parsing the xml file, and parsing and creating UI in the same thread at the same time is making my app non-responsive, thats why the AsyncTak()

Comment: @YellowJK- could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the methods called in the `onPostExecuted`  gets the control of the **UI thread**,I hope that may be the cause as the **parsing** that you are doing is still done on the **UI thread** and so your *application stops responding* as it would be `parsing` the data.

Use **onPreExecute()** to start the `ProgressDialog` like this way.Declare the `ProgressDialog` `Globally` at the Top.

```
ProgressDialog pd;
```

**Start** it in the `onPreExecute` Method.

```
 @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
          pd=ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this,"","Please Wait");
        }
```

Call these both methods in **doInBackground** Itself at the Bottom.Don't call it in the **PostExecute** Method so that it gets `executed` in the **BackGround**

```
ParseDocument(d); 
text();
```

**Now,** in the PostExecute method,dismiss the progressDialog.

```
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(Document d) {
          pd.dismiss();  //Dismiss the Progress Dialog 
        }
```

Comment: when i am calling my ParseDocument() method in doInBackground() it is saying unreachable code..

Comment: Don't go on to return dom1; And befrore return statement,call ParseDocument()and text().
Return null from doInBackground() and ParseDocument() should be called before returning the Value.I hope you may be returning the value and then calling the ParseDocument() method.

Comment: Oh..i am sorry for the syntax problem...use this way..i will edit my answer..pd=ProgressDialog.show(XML_PARSER.this,"","Please Wait");

Comment: i got that already, but the progressDialog box is not going, its stuck at please wait.
and the logcat shows "the application may be doing too much work on the main thread"....
                  its just skipping frames.

Comment: whenever any Method is updating your UI from doInBackground(),you have to use this method inside of doInBackground() to update it.  runOnUI()

Comment: yes it did, you were right about calling the method in doInBackground(), though i am still testing it if there is an obstacle i hope you will be here only to help.

Comment: ya..i will...and please put this thread to Solved by accepting my answer as Correct..you should credit me that much man..:::)))

Comment: sorry dude , totally forgot about that.

Comment: :::)))...tell me if you had further problem...will reply you when i am free...ok

Comment: in the getOption(Element el,Node parent) method,go on to print values using Log.i("name",value)...so that you can trace where you get stop.In the fillSubOptions(op, el, parent) method also go on to print the flags like you reached inside of fillSubOptions method,print the values of the variables used their,because I know that NULL value parsing is a real headache and you will have to handle that and like wise..you have to find out where you get stoped.And this way you can trace that.

Comment: i have already figured out the problem, neways thanks again for replying. The problem was in my printSubOptions() in Option class.